# Flutter Layout: How can I put a Row inside a Flex (or another Row) in Flutter? Also using Stack widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I need to put 2 composed widgets in one `Row`:

The composed widget is named "boxText". I need it twice, each inside a Border with two `Texts` and a `TextFormField` like:

```
Stack
  Image and others
  Form
    Row or Flex or Whatever:
    +------------------------------+    +------------------------------+
    | Text  Text TextFormField     |    | Text Text  TextFormField     |
    +------------------------------+    +------------------------------+
```

My code (and tears):
IMPORTANT: Exception occurs only when `TextFormField` is added.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// Composed Widget
 Widget boxText = new Container(
  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
    border: new Border.all(
      color: Colors.cyan[100],
      width: 3.0,
      style: BorderStyle.solid,
    ),
  ),
  margin: new EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
  padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  child: new Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[
      new Text(
        'Text',
        style: null,
      ),
      new Text(
        'Text',
        style: null,
      ),
      new TextFormField(
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
          hintText: '',
          labelText: 'label',
        ),
        obscureText: true,
      ),
    ],
  ),
);

return new Scaffold(
  key: _scaffoldKey,
  body: new Stack(
    alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topStart,
    textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    fit: StackFit.loose,
    overflow: Overflow.clip,
    children: <Widget>[

      new Container(
        color: Colors.red[200],
        margin: new EdgeInsets.only(
          left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.05,
          right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.05,
          top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.4,
          bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
        ),
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: new Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: new ListView(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
            children: <Widget>[
              new Flex(
                direction: Axis.horizontal,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  boxText,
                  boxText,
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
    );
  }
```

How, if possible, can put this widgets to work without:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞══

The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():

An InputDecorator, which is typically created by a TextField, cannot 
have an unbounded width.

This happens when the parent widget does not provide a finite width 
constraint. For example, if the InputDecorator is contained by a Row, 
then its width must be constrained. An Expanded widget or a SizedBox 
can be used to constrain the width of the InputDecorator or the 
TextField that contains it.

'package:flutter/src/material/input_decorator.dart':

Failed assertion: line 945 pos 7: 'layoutConstraints.maxWidth < 
double.infinity'
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Wrap BOTH your `Container` and `TextFormField` inside a `Flexible` widget.

[image]

```
Widget boxText = new Flexible(child: new Container(
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        border: new Border.all(
          color: Colors.cyan[100],
          width: 3.0,
          style: BorderStyle.solid,
        ),
      ),
      margin: new EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: new Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[

          new Text(
            'Text',
            style: null,
          ),
          new Text(
            'Text',
            style: null,
          ),
          new Flexible (child: new TextFormField(
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              hintText: '',
              labelText: 'label',
            ),
            obscureText: true,
          ),),
        ],
      ),
    ));
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your Container is relying on its parent to decide its width. Since it has no parent, it is infinitely wide.

To fix the problem, give it a parent who tells its child how to handle width. A Flexible or Expanded does that. Expanded tells its child to be as big as possible (to expand) and a Flexible tells its child to be as small as possible (to shrink).

It sounds to me like an Expanded would be your best bet:

Change your code:

```
// Composed Widget
Widget boxText = new Container(
  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
  // all your other code here
);
```

to

```
// Composed Widget
Widget boxText = Expanded(   // <-- Add this Expanded widget
  child: new Container(
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
    // all your other code here
  ),
);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
         child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(

                      decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "text"),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text("unit"),
                ],
              )),
```

Comment: add Expanded will ok